# How can I build BaseGameUtils with Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx, google-play-games

I had a project that was working fine until I imported the `BaseGameUtils` library project for use with my project.

Is it possible to continue to use Gradle to build my project? I tried the [*Google Play Game Services in LibGDX*](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX) instructions. Even though they are for IntelliJ - I would think the instructions would work for Eclipse but they don't.

The error I get is

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

This is from adding the line `compile project(":BaseGameUtils")` in my `:android dependencies` in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need add this project to Gradle. Just import `BaseGameUtils` to Eclipse, then set it as a library

*Right button on **BaseGameUtils** > **properties** > **Android** > check **"Is a library**" > click **ok***

Then go to your Android project (not the core project)

***Properties*** > **Android** > **Add library** > select **BaseGameUtils**

Try to follow [LibGDX Google Play Game Services Tutorial](http://theinvader360.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html?m=1).

Comment: But I want to be able to build my project from Gradle command line. I have been following that tutorial but have other issues as well.

Comment: It's better to include the basegameutils library with grandle because this way you do not have to care about using the correct version of the Google play services library required by the basegameutils library